# def index how to find forum_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a little forum. I have Models  Forum,Topic,Posts.
And I want to show last Topics at the each forums.

This is my models

## app/models/forum.rb

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :topics
end
```

## app/models/topic.rb

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :forum
end
```

## app/controllers/forum_controller.rb

```
def index
    @forums = Forum.all
    @topics = Topic.all
    @topic = @topics.last_topics
end
```

## app/views/forums/index.html.slim

```
- @forums.each do |forum|           
    tr.dotted                      
        td.yach 
            = image_tag('forumico.png') 
            u = link_to forum.name, forum_path(forum)   
            br
            p = forum.desc
        td = forum.topics.count 
        td = forum.views_count
        td 
            = distance_of_time_in_words_to_now forum.updated_at
            |  назад
            - @topic.each do |topic|
                = topic.name

        td
```

and at the browser i see on each forum  last topic for all...

Example:

```
 Forum_list                            Last_topic
 Forum_name 1                           topic#9
 Forum_name 2                           topic#9
 Forum_name 3                           topic#9
```

What i want:

```
  Forum_list                            Last_topic
 Forum_name 1                           topic#9
 Forum_name 2                           topic#23
 Forum_name 3                           topic#76
```

How to do it? Thx

Comment: Your information is not sufficient. Show your model relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to has_many relationship `forum.topics` get the all topics for the particular topic and `forum.topics.last.name` get the name of last topic.

```
- @forums.each do |forum|           
    tr.dotted                      
      td.yach 
        = image_tag('forumico.png') 
        u = link_to forum.name, forum_path(forum)   
        br
        p = forum.desc
    td = forum.topics.count
    td = forum.views_count
    td 
        = distance_of_time_in_words_to_now forum.updated_at
        |  назад
        - forum.topics.last.name if forum.topics.any?

    td
```

Comment: and  forum.topics.last.name   is Topic, Topic, Topic... :(

Comment: what you exactly want to do is display the last topic name for every forum.

Comment: Yes.. i want to do it.

Comment: look forum.topics.last get you the last topic for the forum , then do what you want with it .

Comment: can you paste the output of `forum.topics.last.name`

Comment: NoMethodError in Forums#index
Showing /home/lucker/git/s-p/app/views/forums/index.html.slim where line #21 raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass,    - forum.topics.last.name  this is line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93691/discussion-between-pardeep-saini-and--).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use an [association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) between `topics` and `forums`:

```
#app/models/forum.rb
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :topics
end

#app/models/topic.rb
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :forum
   scope :latest, ->(limit = 1) { order(created_at: :desc).limit(limit) } 
end
```

This way, you can call the following:

```
#app/controllers/forums_controller.rb
class ForumsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @forums = Forum.all
   end
end

#app/views/forums/index.html.erb
<% @forum.each do |forum| %>
   <% forum.topics.latest do |topic| %>
      <%= topic.title %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: dont work....  15 дня назад#<Topic::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x00000008f8efc8>   but i used         = forum.topics.latest do |topic|
        = topic.name

Comment: You'll have to give me more than that. What was the line where the error appeared?